# TCL Group list number by rule

Tags: algorithm, tcl

Currently, I use TCL 8.5. I have a list of numbers that have rule to group. How can I group it by the following rule

```
{1 1 1 1} ==> "1*4"
{1 1 1 2 2 3} ==> "1*3,2*2,3"
{1 3 5 7 1 3 5 7} ==> "(1,3,5,7)*2"
```

Thanks

Comment: The third rule is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
proc rule list {
    foreach item $list {
        incr n($item)
    }
    join [lmap digit [lsort [array names n]] {
        if {$n($digit) == 1} {
            format %d $digit
        } else {
            format %d*%d $digit $n($digit)
        }
    }] ,
}
```

The `lmap` command is Tcl 8.6, but it has been [backported](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) to 8.5. The procedure can also be written without `lmap`:

```
proc rule list {
    foreach item $list {
        incr n($item)
    }
    foreach digit [lsort [array names n]] {
        if {$n($digit) == 1} {
            lappend items [format %d $digit]
        } else {
            lappend items [format %d*%d $digit $n($digit)]
        }
    }
    join $items ,
}
```

The above snippets handle the first two cases in the question. To handle all the cases, something like this is needed:

```
proc rule list {
    if {[llength $list] < 1} {
        return
    }
    foreach item $list {
        incr n($item)
    }
    foreach {item count} [array get n] {
        lappend m($count) $item
    }
    foreach count [lsort -integer -decreasing [array names m]] {
        if {[llength $m($count)] > 1} {
            set item ([join [lsort $m($count)] ,])
        } else {
            set item $m($count)
        }
        if {$count > 1} {
            append item *$count
        }
        lappend items $item
    }
    join $items ,
}
```

Documentation:
[< (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[== (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[> (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm),
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Is there any way to implement by TCL 8.5? I meet the error "invalid command name "lmap"" when using this proc

Comment: @ThinhNguyen: look at the documentation links.

Comment: This proc does not correct in case {1 3 5 7 1 3 5 7} ==> "(1,3,5,7)*2"

Comment: @ThinhNguyen: as noted in the text. Hint: check if all values in the `n` array are equal.

Comment: @ThinhNguyen: and again: thought of a simpler way to do it.